# Using glue to include information regarding selected observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my ggplot to display the state I had selected for better clarity but it seems like glue is only seeking for the first observation rather than my desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
death_state=read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MoH-Malaysia/covid19-public/main/epidemic/deaths_state.csv")
death_state=death_state%>%
  select(date,state,deaths_new,deaths_new_dod)%>%
  filter(between(date,max(date)-months(6),max(date)))%>%
  rename(Reported=deaths_new,Actual=deaths_new_dod)%>%
  pivot_longer(c(Reported,Actual),names_to="Reported/Actual",values_to="Deaths")%>%
  rename_with(str_to_title)%>%
  mutate(State=ifelse(State %in% c("W.P. Kuala Lumpur","Selangor","W.P. Putrajaya"), 'Klang Valley', State)) %>%
  group_by(Date,State,`Reported/Actual`) %>%
  summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths), .groups = 'drop')
```

Up until this point, the dataframe produced is as follow:

```
# A tibble: 5,180 x 4
   Date       State        `Reported/Actual` Deaths
   <date>     <chr>        <chr>              <dbl>
 1 2021-03-11 Johor        Actual                 1
 2 2021-03-11 Johor        Reported               2
 3 2021-03-11 Kedah        Actual                 0
 4 2021-03-11 Kedah        Reported               0
 5 2021-03-11 Kelantan     Actual                 0
 6 2021-03-11 Kelantan     Reported               1
 7 2021-03-11 Klang Valley Actual                 3
 8 2021-03-11 Klang Valley Reported               5
 9 2021-03-11 Melaka       Actual                 0
10 2021-03-11 Melaka       Reported               0
# ... with 5,170 more rows
```

When I tried to run the following code, it will only display the first observation rather than the state selected and hence I appreciate any help for this. Thank you.

```
death_state%>%
  filter(State %in% "Kedah")%>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(fill=`Reported/Actual`,x=Date,y=Deaths,colour=`Reported/Actual`))+
  geom_line(size=0.75)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","firebrick2"))+
  labs(title=glue("Deaths by State
                  {death_state$State}"))
```

[image]

Comment: Check out the answer. Does it solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is showing the death for Kedah only, but it is printing Johor in the title.

Instead of editing it every time in the ggplot2 code, I prefer to create a separate list and filter it out in the ggplot2 code.

And, instead of `glue`, I used a simple `paste0`.

Solution:

```
selected_state <- 'Kedah'

death_state%>%
  filter(State %in% selected_state)%>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(fill=`Reported/Actual`,x=Date,y=Deaths,colour=`Reported/Actual`))+
  geom_line(size=0.75)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","firebrick2"))+
  ggtitle(paste0('Deaths by State: \n', selected_state))
```

[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any more queries!